# Is there a Python (np/cv2/etc.) function for pixel neighbors probing?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I have some binary image, from which are want to extract data about lines, their coordinates and width, for further classification.

I've tried cv2.Canny, but it's provide poor quality for my needs, so I need more manual, step by step solution for every pixel.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


path = '../img/1.jpg'


img = cv2.imread(path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
dilate = cv2.dilate(blur, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=3)

threshold = cv2.threshold(dilate, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, threshold = threshold

canny = cv2.Canny(threshold, 128, 255)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
dc = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("canny", canny)
cv2.imshow("dc", dc)

while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey()
    q = 113
    esc = 27
    if key == q or key == esc:
        break
```

I want to find out more precise method of finding contours coordinate and classify it.

[image: lines prober]

*lines prober*

[image: idea]

*idea*

[image: canny is bad]

*canny is bad*

[image: source]

*source*

Comment: Could you state a more direct question?

Comment: Can you include an unedited source image so that others can try your code?

Comment: @StephenMeschke sure

Comment: Could you provide more details on your goal? Your question is ambiguous

Comment: It's hard to explain, so that why I asked for help, and draw some images

Comment: I want to classify line thickness and get it coordinates

Comment: matrix analysis? graphs? I really don't know what I need to google